# App crashes under EXC_BAD_ACCESS creating an instance of a client in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

After the upgrade to swift 2.2 and xcode 7.3 my app crashes creating an instance of a client of services. The client I describe below:

ApiClient.swift

```js
class ApiClient {

  var clubsService:      ClubsService
  var eventsService:     EventsService
  var friendsService:    FriendsService
  var mainService:       MainService
  var mediaItemsService: MediaItemsService
  var partiesService:    PartiesService
  var usersService:      UsersService


  init() {
    clubsService      = ClubsService()
    eventsService     = EventsService()
    friendsService    = FriendsService()
    mainService       = MainService()
    mediaItemsService = MediaItemsService()
    partiesService    = PartiesService()
    usersService      = UsersService()
  }
}
```

And the app crashes, under the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error, in the declaration of an instance of the client inside of view controller trying to declare one instance of the client to be able to use the services. Below I describe the viewcontroller and the point of the error:

```js
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

  let apiClient = ApiClient() <-- EXC_BAD_ACCESS code = 2 <--
  var flyers: [Flyer]!
  var events: [Event]!


  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

   super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    print("MainController viewWillAppear")

    apiClient.mainService.List() { flyers, error in
      if flyers != nil {
        self.flyers = flyers
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.actInd.stopAnimating()
      } else {
        print("error: \(error)")
      }
    }
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.flyers?.count ?? 0
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mainObjectCell") as! MainTableViewCell
    cell.mainObject = self.flyers?[indexPath.row]
    return cell
  }
  }

}
```

Before the upgrade the App worked, but now don't.
If I call the service directly from the viewcontroller the app works but I want to maintain the client. 
I was trying with NSZombies but I dont see anything

Comment: You should set break point in your `init()` of `ApiClient` to make sure every class instances is instantiated correctly.

Comment: sorry but I've set a breakpoint in the init() but the app crashes before that.

Comment: I've found the error, just change class by struct